# Find the index of the last negative value of an increasing function

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I have some increasing function and a range of values, I would like to find the last index for which this function is still negative, as a minimal working example we have:

```
def f(x):
    return x-7
x_range = np.linspace(-10,10,num=1000)
n = next(n for n, x in enumerate(x_range) if f(x) < 0) - 1
```

this works, and for this example would be a fine solution. However: For my example, the computation time of evaluating the function `f` is more like 1 minute so doing this it this way is very cumbersome. Moreover I already have a guess for where the value `n` should be. I can write my own program looking for the value by mimicking some algorithm for finding roots of functions but I was wondering if there was some easy built-in way to do this?

Comment: How about calculating the derivative and finding the slopes (signs)? Would that be an option?

Comment: Yes this is an option, but surely this must have a general implementation? (my function  `f` is not linear)

Comment: Also your example **should not** work. `next` gives you the next element that satisfies your constrains. not the last one that does so. I am not sure what the `-1` is there for.

Comment: have you looked into [`sympy`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html#derivatives)?

Comment: If the function is well behaved (changing from positive to negative only once) you will want to do [bisection search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method). If you want a built-in solution have a look at scipy's [root finding](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#root-finding) functions. (Once you have the root you should easily be able to get the nearest negative grid point.)

Comment: @kasemakase: You are right I can just do `bisect` and set the number of steps allowed to a small value, thank you!
@Ev.Kounis : Thank you for your response, about `next`: I think it should work: it keeps looping through the list until it finds a value for which `f(x) >= 0` and then returns the index of this `x`

Comment: @HolyMonk but `f(x) >= 0` is not what your code on the Question says. The -1 I get now. And yes, in that case it is fine

Comment: @Ev.Kounis : It keeps searching as long as `f(x) < 0` when this doesn't hold it returns the first index for which `f(x) >= 0 ` and I subtract one from this value. But the answer of @kazemakase is satisfactory to my question so - Problem Solved!

Comment: @kazemakase I implemented it for my problem and it works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: @HolyMonk No, it doesn't keep searching as long as `f(x) < 0`. It returns immediately as soon as `f(x) < 0`.

Comment: @HolyMonk good to hear! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `bisect` from the standard lib (not the scipy one). You just need to trick it into believing it is dealing with an array.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import bisect
>>> 
>>> class fake_array:
...     def __init__(self, f, rng):
...         self.f, self.rng = f, rng
...     def __getitem__(self, x):
...         return self.f(self.rng[x])
...     def __len__(self):
...         return len(self.rng)
... 
>>> def f(x):
...     return x-7
... 
>>> x_range = np.linspace(-10,10,num=1000)
>>>
>>> bisect.bisect_left(fake_array(f, x_range), 0) - 1
849
```

You can also restrict to a subrange:

```
>>> bisect.bisect_left(fake_array(f, x_range), 0, 800, 900) - 1
849
```